# Pattern matching with gcloud --filter

Tags: gcloud

I want to get a list of tags matching a certain pattern and to do that I have been using the command:

`gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/project/reposiory --format="json" --filter="tags:*_master"`

but I'm getting this warning:

`` WARNING: --filter : operator evaluation is changing for consistency across Google APIs.  tags:*_master currently matches but will not match in the near future.  Run `gcloud topic filters` for details. ``

I've searched around but can't find how I'm supposed to do this going forwards. Does anyone know how I can match a pattern in this way i.e. all tags that end with "_master"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters#Operator-Terms), you could use a regular expression.

To use a regular expression, you would use `--filter="key ~ value`. In this case, `key` would be 'tags'. For `value`, you would want to match anything that ends with '_master'. You can use a `$` in a regular expression to anchor to the end of the string.

Combining all this, your new filter would be: `--filter="tags ~ _master$"`

Answer (score 1):

From the **[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters#Operator-Terms)**. Your warning message is caused due to the following:

> **The operator evaluation is changing for consistency across Google APIs. The current default is deprecated and will be dropped shortly. A warning will be displayed when a --filter expression would return different matches using both the deprecated and new implementations.**

Please refer to the previously mentioned **[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters#Operator-Terms)** to make sure that you are using the correct matches.